# how to refer to the web component itself?

Tags: polymer, lit-element

Inside the web component, I can use the CSS selector `:host` to select the web component itself.

In js, I can refer to `this.shadowRoot`, but not exactly the web component. Is there a way to refer to the web component in js?

Comment: I tried `this`, it works, hahah

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript the caller context(where happens) and how you call a function (simple calling by test() or by new keyword) defines the functions **this**, for example:

```
function test(){
  console.log(this);
}

test();//shows window
new test()// creates an brand new object and assign it to test's this
```

Web components (specifically here its custom element's part)definition is done by *customElements.define* which assigns the created element as **this**, so you can refer to it in every method of it by default:

```
window.customElements.define('test-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
   super();

   this.addEventListener("click", () => {
   // this means 'test-element' DOM
   });
  }
});
```